# How do I adjust the title text font size for my UITabBarController?

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am using a `UITabBarController` but I only have 2 tabs. Instead of using icons I just want to use text. I created a bar item title but the text is very small and I'm having a hard time modifying it. How can I make a bar item just text that fits the section reasonably?

I've tried to change the font size programmatically but I'm fairly new to swift and am struggling.

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
        UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white], for: .selected)

        UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.lightGray], for: .normal)


        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For each of the `UIViewController` in `UITabBarController`, call `setTitleTextAttributes(_:for:)` on controller's `tabBarItem` in `viewDidLoad()`, i.e.

```
class VC1: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes([.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.0, weight: .regular)], for: .normal)

    }
}

class VC2: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes([.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.0, weight: .regular)], for: .normal)
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Since you've created the `controllers` of `tabBarController` in the `storyboard`, here is how you can get that working.

Subclass `UITabBarController` and set the `titleTextAttributes` of its ``` viewControllers`` ```tabBarItem`in`viewDidLoad()`, i.e.

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.viewControllers?.forEach({
            $0.tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes([.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.0, weight: .regular)], for: .normal)
        })
    }
}
```

Now set `TabBarController` as `class` of `UITabBarController` in `storyboard`.

I hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: I added "self.tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes([.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.0, weight: .regular)], for: .selected)" The issue I'm having is that when the app initially loads the unselected bar item title has small text. After selecting it once it begins to function the way I want it to. How can I get the text attributes to apply at the time the app launches?

Comment: Are you adding the controllers in storyboard or programatically?

Comment: I added the controllers using storyboard.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Checkout the **Edit:** part of the answer and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The UITextAttributeFont was deprecated in iOS 7. You should use the NS variant instead:

```
import UIKit

let appearance = UITabBarItem.appearance()
let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font:UIFont(name: "Your font style", size: 20)]
appearance.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any], for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "FontName", size: 10)!], for: .normal)
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "FontName", size: 10)!], for: .selected)